# Help with this definition of $(G:_M I)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, definition

I didn't understand why in this definition $I$ has to be an ideal to make sense.

[image]

**REMARK**

This is from [Steps in Commutative Algebra](http://books.google.com.br/books/about/Steps_in_Commutative_Algebra.html?id=Oi4x9NznFEUC&redir_esc=y), page 107.

Thanks a lot

Comment: It would still make sense and $(G : I)$ would still be a submodule, but you could make this complaint about a lot of definitions in (commutative) algebra.

Comment: If you spend the time to check the details about why it's a submodule, you'll see clearly you don't need anything about $I$'s idealness. However, I agree that phrasing it in the way  this book is makes one a little paranoid :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition doesn't claim that $I$ has to be an ideal, and in fact it doesn't, but if $S$ is any subset of $R$ then $(G :_M S) = (G :_M I)$ where $I$ is the ideal generated by $S$, so $I$ *might as well be* an ideal.